# FileMerge showing wrong content for XIB files

Tags: xcode, xib, filemerge

When FileMerge compares XIB files, the displayed contents are completely different from the actual contents. Instead of an interface builder document (the root is `<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Cocoa.XIB" ...>`), FileMerge shows plists (the first key is "com.apple.ibtool.document.classes"). Why is this? Can FileMerge work with XIB files, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileMerge filters some files, based on extension. XIB are run through ibtool (which appears in the first key in the plist).

To disable (which is recommended over deleting):

1. In FileMerge, open preferences (FileMerge → Preferences, or <kbd>⌘,</kbd>)
2. Open the "Filters" tab
3. Double-click on the "xib" cell in the "Extension" column.
4. Alter the entry (e.g. append "_") so the filter won't match XIB files.

Note the "Display" column cells are toggles; clicking on them will switch between "Filtered" and "Original". However, an attempt to disable the "xib" filter by switching to "Original" resulted in the error:

> Filter $(DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR)/ibtool --all $(FILE) is not working properly.  The number of newlines cannot change as a result of filtering.